# How to find the actual scrollbar height inside a scrollviewer control

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I'm trying to make smart scrolling for a canvas that expands in size. I want the scrollbars to automatically go to the center of their range. So I use:

```
eagleViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(drawingSpace.Height/2);
eagleViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(drawingSpace.Width/2);
```

Which works but when the scrollbars scroll they go beyond the half point, it seems it's top aligned. So I wanted to subtract the scrollbar Height or Width so the scrollbars would be perfectly centered at the canvas.

I read in other posts that I can do this is at

```
SystemParameters.ScrollHeight
```

or

```
SystemParameters.ScrollWidth
```

But how does that work? I have multiple scrollviewers in the window. I want the height or width of the scrollbars of this specific scrollviewer.

Any other way I'm not aware off?

Thanks

Edit:

Adding XAML section:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="eagleViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                        <Grid Name="eagleGrid" Background="LightGray">
                            <Canvas Name="drawingSpace" Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="100" Height="100">
                                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomEagleSlider,Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomEagleSlider,Path=Value}"/>
                                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add another answer here because I like to post some more code. You gave the right keyword: "The canvas height change happens on the line before i run the scrolltoverticaloffset code". By doing this I can reproduce the problem. The problem is the ScrollViewer obviously evaluates the ScrollableHeight property at a later point. Which means you need to delay using ScrollableHeight. It is a bit tricky to find the right point. In my following test application I use the first ScrollChanged event after the content's height was changed to center the scrollbar.

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollViewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="SV"
                      Margin="71,62,10,10"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Border x:Name="SVContent" Background="#FFFFA6A6"
                        BorderBrush="#FF005DFF"
                        Width="200"
                        Height="200"
                        BorderThickness="1" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Width="75"
                Margin="28,20,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="Button_Click"
                Content="Button" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ScrollViewer
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            SV.ScrollChanged += ScrollChangedEventHandler;
        }

        bool firstScrollAfterContenChanged;

        private void Button_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            firstScrollAfterContenChanged = true;
            SVContent.Height = 1000;
        }

        public void ScrollChangedEventHandler(Object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (firstScrollAfterContenChanged)
            {
                firstScrollAfterContenChanged = false;
                SV.ScrollToVerticalOffset (SV.ScrollableHeight / 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
        scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollviewer.ScrollableHeight/2);
```

Comment: It didn't work, when debugging I'm getting zero for scrollableheight. the height of the 'space' canvas is around 3000.

Comment: Hm, it does work in my test application. ScrollableHeight is the amout of the ScrollViewer's content that can be moved (scrolled). Lets say the height of the content is 300 and the height of the ScrollViewer is 250, ScrollableHeight is 50. Because your ScrollableHeight is zero that is an indicator the ScrollViewer's height is at least as big as the content's height (which shouldn't be the case). Can you post more XAML code to see more of the environment?

Comment: edited the post with XAML. The Canvas is 100 in this code but when the program runs it gets recalculated and it changes to 3000. The canvas height change happens on the line before i run the scrolltoverticaloffset code.